# How do I change python pygame function from string to function in python?

Tags: python, json, string, pygame

I am trying to convert string to a function like
`A_rect = "pygame.Rect(50, 50, 100, 100)"`
and then under the main loop I want to display it like `pygame.draw.rect(win, (200, 0, 0), a_rect)`
but it wont take a string. Is there any way I can covert it.
I am using json files actually , so my python file is as follows:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
import json

pygame.init()

wind_h, wind_w = 800, 600

wind = pygame.display.set_mode((wind_h, wind_w))
pygame.display.set_caption("No Touch")

spsh = pygame.image.load("Carpets 4.png")

jsonv = open("JSONV.json", "r")
imgs = open("imgs.json", "r")

img_data = json.load(imgs)
data = json.load(jsonv)

def get_image(posx, posy, width, height, sprite_sheet):
    """Extracts image from sprite sheet"""
    image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
    image.blit(sprite_sheet, (0, 0), (posx, posy, width, height))
    image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
    return image

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()


def draw():
    wind.fill((100, 100, 100))
    for i in data['Room-1']:
        #print(data['Room-1'][str(i)]['w'])
        #pygame.draw.rect(wind, (255, 0, 0), pygame.Rect(data['Room-1'][str(i)]['x'], data['Room-1'][str(i)]['y'], data['Room-1'][str(i)]['w'], data['Room-1'][str(i)]['h']))
        wind.blit(get_image(0, 0, img_data['water']['w'], img_data['water']['h'], spsh), pygame.Rect(data['Room-1'][str(i)]['x'], data['Room-1'][str(i)]['y'], data['Room-1'][str(i)]['w'], data['Room-1'][str(i)]['h']))
        #wind.blit(spsh, pygame.Rect(2, 2, 4, 4))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            terminate()


    draw()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

and this is my main jsonv.json file:

```
{
"Room-1" : {
    "rect0" : {
        "w": 500,
        "h": 500,
        "x": 4,
        "y": 4
    },
    "rect1" : {
        "w": 500,
        "h": 500,
        "x": 24,
        "y": 4
    },
    "rect2" : {
        "w": 500,
        "h": 500,
        "x": 44,
        "y": 4
    },
    "rect3" : {
        "w": 500,
        "h": 500,
        "x": 64,
        "y": 4
    },
    "rect4" : {
        "w": 500,
        "h": 500,
        "x": 4,
        "y": 24
    },
    "rect5" : {
        "w": 500,
        "h": 500,
        "x": 24,
        "y": 24
    },
    "rect6" : {
        "w": 500,
        "h": 500,
        "x": 44,
        "y": 24
    },
    "rect7" : {
        "w": 500,
        "h": 500,
        "x": 64,
        "y": 24
    },
    "rect8" : {
        "w": 500,
        "h": 500,
        "x": 4,
        "y": 44
    },
    "rect9" : {
        "w": 500,
        "h": 500,
        "x": 24,
        "y": 44
    },
    "rect10" : {
        "w": 500,
        "h": 500,
        "x": 44,
        "y": 44
    },
    "rect11" : {
        "w": 500,
        "h": 500,
        "x": 64,
        "y": 44
    }

  }
}
```

Here I want to replace rect with `"rect1": "pygame.Rect(500, 500, 4, 4)"`
So is there any way to convert string into function?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try convert it with ```eval()```.

Comment: ok will try @HenryTjhia, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using exec command.
for example if you have a string temp_string = "print('hello world')"
and you want to execute this string as a command in python
then you should use exec() function as

exec(temp_string)

so in your case it should be exec("pygame.Rect(50, 50, 100, 100)")

I think it should work.